# implementing a binary search tree - "incompatible types when returning type 'struct item_t *'..."

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, binary-search

I'm trying to implement a binary search tree that holds an inventory of ordered stock. The stocked item attributes are stored in nodes as such:

```
typedef struct item item_t;
struct item{
    char name;
    int price;
    int quantity;
    item_t *left;
    item_t *right;
};
```

The idea is to prompt a user to enter the above attributes, and then add the entered item to a node. This is what I've written so far:

```
item_t *root = NULL;
item_t *current_leaf = NULL;

void prompt_user(){
    /*
    In here contains the code that prompts the user for the item attributes
    and stores it in a variable called input
    */
    insert_node(input);
}

void insert_node(char *input){
    /*If tree doesnt have a root...*/
    if (root == NULL){

        /*Create one...*/
        root = create_node(input);
    }

    else{
        item_t *cursor = root;
        item_t *prev = NULL;
        int is_left = 0;
        int comparison;

        while(cursor != NULL){

            /*comparison will be 1 is the key of input is less than the key   
            of the cursor, and 2 otherwise...*/
            comparison = compare(input, cursor);
            prev = cursor;

            if(comparison == 1){
                is_left = 1;
                cursor = cursor->left;
            }
            else if (comparison == 2){
                is_left = 0;
                cursor = cursor->right;
            }
        }

        if(is_left){
            *prev->left = create_node(input);
            current_leaf = prev->left;
        }
        else{
            *prev->right = create_node(input);
            current_leaf = prev->right;
        }
    }
}

item_t create_node(char *input){

    item_t *new_node = (item_t*)malloc(sizeof(item_t));

    if (new_node == NULL){
        printf("Out of memory. Shutting down.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Add data to the node...*/
    update_item(input, new_node);

    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;

    current_leaf = new_node;

    return new_node;
}
```

I want `root` to always be pointing to the first item ever entered, and `current_leaf` to be pointing to the last item processed. `compare` returns 1 if the item being processed (`input`) is less than the last processed item (`current_leaf`). `update_item` is what sets the data for the new nodes (leaves).

The above isn't fully complete, but it's what I'm up to at the moment. I'm struggling to work out how to write `add_node` and how to keep `current_leaf` updated correctly.

When I try to compile I get the following errors:

```
$ gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -o proj2.exe proj2.c
 proj2.c: In function 'insert_node':
 proj2.c:416:14: error: incompatible types when assigning to type'structitem_t *' from type 'item_t'
         root = create_node(input);
               ^
 proj2.c: In function 'create_node':
 proj2.c:470:5: error: incompatible types when returning type 'struct item_t *' but 'item_t' was expected
      return new_node;
      ^
```

Comment: `root` is of type `item_t*` while `create_node` returns `item_t`. The same thing happens here :`return new_node;`(`new_node` is of type `item_t*` , but `create_node` is designed to return an `item_t`). You probably want `item_t *create_node(char *input)` instead of `item_t create_node(char *input)`. This would fix both the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
item_t create_node(char *input)
```

should be

```
item_t *create_node(char *input)
```

What you return is a structure but you should be returning pointer of type `struct item`.